# Bulk Dequeue from Oracle Queue using Standalone Java

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle10g, oracle11g

I want to dequeue the messages from Oracle AQ. Oracle is enqueuing data into table called parser.

Since we're asked not to use JMS or any such feature due to deadline, I need a standalone program which will dequeue messages from this queue.

Can any one provide me the sample code in Java which will dequeue messages? Also, we need to dequeu messages in bulk & not one by one.

I'll appreciate if some one can provide standalone java sample to retrieve bulk dequeued messages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to dequeue the messages from Oracle AQ. Oracle is enqueuing
>   data into table called parser.

I'm confused about queue and table in the same question.

If it's a queue, then write a `MessageListener` and have it listen to the queue.  When messages arrive, it'll receive and process them.

If it's a table, write a task that periodically does a JDBC queue to `SELECT` all the rows in the table, process, and delete them as a single transaction.

Comment: Whenever there is an insert into one of our table, Oracle puts that record into the queue. And I want to have a program in Java which will dequeue all these messages continuously. Also, I need to dequeu bulk messages & not record by record. Can you provide sample code?

Comment: No samples from me.  Your best bet is to have a look at the Oracle docs.  I'm sure they have an example or two.